# Different Headers in StackNavigator

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have implemented a StackNavigator in which I removed the header for styles purpose.

Now I have a Component inside the StackNavigator for which I'd like to get the header back. How do you reckon I do it ?

Here is my StackNavigator :

```
const Nav = StackNavigator(
{
    SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Register: {screen: Register},
    Main: {screen: MainNav},
},
{
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

But for the Register screen, I would like to have a header (to let the user know that he can go back).

I tried doing this :

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Register',
    header: {

    }
}
```

But I don't quite know what to put inside the header part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally what i did: I had set the height of the header to 0 when i didnt want it to show and to n to show it so i could do somenthing like 
`height: condition ? 0 : 10`

otherwise someone answered [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1534)

> You can do it programmatically with the following code:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({   header:
> (navigation.state.params.thanks) => <HeaderView
> content={navigation.state.params.thanks} /> : null, })
```

> And then you
>   can set the state params with this:

```
componentWillMount() {   this.props.navigation.setParams({ thanks:"Something" }); }
```

> Although I haven't tried the code myself and I'm not
>   sure if something like the HeaderView is accessible for the public api
>   in react-navigation and if there is a content property on that. But I
>   think in an abstract way, this is how you set it programmatically.

I didn't try it either but it might work

---

Edit:  the answer given in github is definitely better, you can import HeaderView from react-navigation and do `header: condition ? HeaderView : null` to show and hide it